# How to use OkHttp to connect to SPDY website?

Tags: java, okhttp, spdy

I can't get OkHttp to connect to https://www.google.com using SPDY. I used the simplest code sample to send a GET request to the site, and added a bunch of logs in the OkHttp source code to realize that the code kept creating HttpConnection, not a single SPDYConnection. Also, the ConnectionPool was empty the whole time. I am sure I was missing something because I couldn't get any of the biggest benefits: connection pooling and SPDY to work in OkHttp.

My client code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://www.google.com").build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

Why:

- No SPDY connection was created?
- ConnectionPool was always empty, no connection was recycled?

What is the 'correct' way to connect to SPDY website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:/home/lee/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/npn/npn-boot/1.1.7.v20140316/npn-boot-1.1.7.v20140316.jar
```

to JVM args fixed it for me. Now I can see SPDY connection is up.

Comment: still have no idea how to turn on this on Android. SPDY with OkHttp on Android is not working for me.

Comment: Which Android release are you using? OkHttp requires Android 4.1+ for NPN on Android.